# Pass res.locals value to client side JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, barcode

I am trying to use the node package `jsbarcode` to generate barcodes. I need to be able to pass in variables from `res.locals` into a file called `main.js` which is in my public directory. Reason for this is that I need the barcodes to be generated on page load using data that is passed into the template using  `res.locals`

**html:**

`<img id="barcode"/>`

**main.js:**

```
JsBarcode("#barcode", amodel + "-" + aNum, {
  format: "CODE128C",
  ean128: true
});
```

I am not sure the `amodel + "-" + aNum` is even the correct format but essentially I need to be able to pass in a string then a `-` then a number before generating the bar code. I would also like to be able to change the format of the bar code as well but that is not priority one.

**TLDR:**

How do I pass variable data into a client side js file?

Comment: typically you would make an ajax call to get the data maybe on page load you make this call. Pending on your situation there are a few more options: if your page is server side rendered you could create a script tag with the data needed. Or maybe if you access a certain page the backend redirects you to the same page with URL encoded data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this using a work around. I am sure there is a more "proper" way of doing it. Here is the html:

```
<style>
  .hidden {display: none;}
```

```
<div id="test123" class="hidden">{{test}}</div>
   <div id="codeType" class="hidden">{{codeType}}</div>
   <img id="barcode"/>
```

Then the JS in a script tag on the same page:

```
<script>
  var test = document.getElementById("test123").innerHTML;
  var codeType = document.getElementById("codeType").innerHTML;
  $('#barcode').JsBarcode('14374', {format: 'UPC'},{ width: 2, height: 90 });
</script>
```

Pretty much what this equates to is that I pass the res.locals into a hidden div then use `.innerhtml` to extract the value into my variable. This works and I can load it 10/10 times no errors. I am using JSBarCode if anyone is wondering.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass a variable into a js file.  However, in your template you can assign the result to `window`.  For example with ejs templates:

```
<script>
  window.jbarData = '<%-jbarData%>'
</script>
```

Then in your `main.js` you can reference `window.jbarData` and use it as you'd like.  You'll need to update this to use whatever template language you're using.